# Display only closest list elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, navigation, html-lists

Here is [**an example of what I have already**](http://jsfiddle.net/jaakritso/wnVre/4/)

The main functionality works, but now I need to make the controller list smaller, so that it fits better to the screen, as it's fixed positioned.

So, I think it should show next three list-items from active item and 2 previous ones.

Something like this would work, but I think there should be shorter and more convinient way:

```
//Display closest items
$('#historyController li.active').prevAll('li:not(.first)').hide().slice(0,2).show();
$('#historyController li.active').nextAll('li:not(.last)').hide().slice(0,3).show();
```

Any tips for re-factoring current code for better performance would be helpful as well.

Comment: `Something like this would work, but I think there should be shorter and more convinient way` or `any tips for re-factoring current code for better performance would be helpful as well` If nothing is broken and your code works but you are simply looking for an alternative or better approach, this question might be better of on [Stackexchange - Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Not sure if I entirely understand, but does the 'closest' method help you here: http://api.jquery.com/closest/

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul>
   <li>list item 1</li>
   <li>list item 2</li>
   <li class="third-item">list item 3</li>
   <li>list item 4</li>
   <li>list item 5</li>
</ul>

$('li.third-item').next().css('background-color', 'red');
```

Link for the documentation [next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/)

This all items you can use for [tree-traversal](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following jQuery function.

```
<ul id="one" class="level-1">
<li class="item-i">I</li>
<li id="ii" class="item-ii">II
<ul class="level-2">
<li class="item-a">A</li>
<li class="item-b">B
<ul class="level-3">
<li class="item-1">1</li>
<li class="item-2">2</li>
<li class="item-3">3</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="item-c">C</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="item-iii">III</li>
</ul>
```

Jquery function is..

```
$('li.item-a').closest('ul').css('background-color', 'red');
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to be what Algeron is looking for. Please read questions carefully before posting answers.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [.end()](http://api.jquery.com/end/), in order to save on traversing:

```
$('#historyController li.active').prevAll('li:not(.first)').hide().slice(0,2).show().end().end().nextAll('li:not(.last)').hide().slice(0,3).show();
```